# Python - How do I setup gui2py?

Tags: python, wxpython, syntax-error

Final note: I will just use Glade instead of gui2py. It seems to be pretty much the same thing and installs like any other windows binary installer.

---

I've done a clean install of Python 2.7.9, wxPython, and gui2py but when I can't seem to get gui2py working.

Here is a link to the files: https://code.google.com/p/gui2py/source/browse/#hg%253Fstate%253Dclosed

When I run either `python sample.pyw`, `python -m gui.tools.designer`, or `python setup.py install`, I get something like this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\sample.pyw", line 19, in <module>
    import gui          # import gui2py package (shortcuts)
  File "C:\Python27\gui\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .controls import Label, Button, TextBox, CheckBox, ListBox, ComboBox, \
  File "C:\Python27\gui\controls\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .label import Label
  File "C:\Python27\gui\controls\label.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ..component import Control, Spec, EventSpec, InitSpec, StyleSpec
  File "C:\Python27\gui\component.py", line 669
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Similar (If not the same) errors are printed when I run setup.py or some other scripts.

So what is going wrong? Do I need any other packages? How can I fix this?

Comment: what's in the `sample.pyw`? Based on your code above, it seems like the `else:` clause isn't closed/terminated. Can you show more code?

Comment: I think `sample.pyw` is a sample code to demonstrate gui2py. Gui2py is a Visual-Basic-looking program for Python. I added a link to the files above; check them out.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I'll just have to stick with Glade instead.

Comment: Can you confirm that both your gui2py and python are either 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: I installed both 32 bit